# How does the Higgs field impact the wavefunction of quarks near the moment of decay?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, higgs, quarks

> Drastically edited from 2012 version. This may still be some distance from properly stated, but less so than the original.

When a decay event happens, for example producing a quark/antiquark pair; mass and energy from the original system are of course undergoing some transition between states before resulting particles fly off on their new trajectories.

Zooming in on the moment of decay, at the sub-atomic scale, how does the existence of a Higgs field and the permeability of spacetime locally influence the wavefunction of the resulting quarks? Assuming we have such resolution or strong theories.

When this question was originally penned; I specifically was curious about attempting to simulate sub-plank length topological changes (without any particular new information, just boring gradients) and whether the field would very slightly 'bend' certain functions, or more dramatically guide the result.

> Previously I had referred to the following well-known simulation of Higgs Boson decay, but this is not as relevant as I thought a decade ago.

[image: Now well known shape of a Higgs Boson, computer generated from Wikipedia]

Comment: In quantum field theory, you have fields, and then particles are excitations of the field. Quarks get their mass from their interaction with the Higgs field, even when there are no Higgs bosons around, through a sort of frictionless drag induced by the energy in the field. The Higgs boson is an excitation of the Higgs field which has nothing to do with producing mass in quarks, but which does tell us something about the properties of the field... Hopefully there will be a proper answer explaining this.

Comment: BTW: The figure is an *event display* from a simulated event in a particular detector (CMS, I think), it is highly abstracted from the vertex physics. Nothing you see there represents *anything* about the "shape" of a particle: you are only seeing outlines of detector elements and connect-the-dots representations of particle *tracks*. It is very common for particle physicists to elide such niceties because everyone in the room is aware of them, but I think that we should be a least a little clear in talking to the public.

Comment: @dmckee Thanks for putting the confusion fully to rest. I'm at lest partly aware these are only readings of other particles shooting out of the reactions, not the particles themselves. Only (I think by conjecture) aren't the trajectories and charges observed used to verify or find underlying field shapes?

Comment: @dmckee Also, can you direct me to anything which *does* represent anything about the "shape" of particles and vertex physics? (now googling..)

Comment: Garet: After reading over this, it honestly doesn't make any sense to me. "the structure of a Higgs boson flows into that of, for instance, a bottom-antibottom quark pair," for example - what do you mean by structure? Or flowing? Could you try to clarify these things so that it would be more clear what you want to know? Feel free to ask in [chat] about it (even if nobody is there at the time).

Comment: Just wondering about downvotes, I'm simply trying to get an understanding of this. Please help edit the question if you find any inconsistencies or erroneous concepts.

Comment: @Garet: Not my downvote, you are surely sincere, but you should ask a completely different question on more elementary things. The Higgs field doesn't have "structures" like what you are asking about--- you seem to imagine that the elementary particles are little solitons (bump configurations) in a classical field theory, little kinks that turn into one another by a process which resembles the way smoke rings combine, and this is just not true. The particles are quantum excitations of a nearly constant field, so no twists and knots. Except the proton/neutron, these have a soliton description.

Comment: @RonMaimon I'll be giving the reformed question some thought tonight, a bit tired now. Appreciate the guidance. Basically we are trying to render this process, in a way *similar* to how I've seen theoretical renderings of protons and electron probability clouds. Given what you are saying I'm not sure if it is doable in the way I originally thought.

Comment: @GaretClaborn: Oh--- you are asking about the _wavefunctions_ of the Higgs and quarks! This is not so silly, but it is difficult, because the probability cloud description is not relativistically invariant. There is a way to describe highly relativistic collisions in terms of something like wavefunctions, these are the parton distribution functions, but the Higgs itself has relatively simple probability cloud description which is not enlightening--- quark waves make Higgs waves in a relatively simple way.

Comment: @RonMaimon After a whole lot more research, I can finally say, yes. That's much along the lines of what I was trying to ask. I had no idea it would prove so difficult for me lol

Comment: @DavidZ well; many years too late but I think I have slightly improved haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to address your question, though, as David says in the comments, it is evident that you have very little background in elementary particle physics. I will bring over an event much simpler than a display of an event that could show  a Higgs *particle* decay.

[Here is](http://particleadventure.org/all_decay.html) a simple antiproton annihilation event whose end particles are recorded by their passage through a bubble chamber which also has a magnetic field perpendicular to the picture. The antiproton enters from below and hits a proton which is at rest, so not visible, in the bubble chamber liquid. It annihilates and eight pions come out, their momentum measured by the curvature, their mass by the ionisation track.

[image]

Where is the Higgs field in this picture? It permeates everything and at the point of interaction when the pions materialize it has supplied the masses to the quarks and antiquarks that they are made up of.

The simulated Higgs event display you have attached shows the decay products of the *Higgs Boson*. This particle is predicted by the Standard Model and it is necessary to find and confirm it in order to validate the SM. It appears because a Higgs field exists, but it is a particle in the data set of particles predicted and  mostly found by the SM. [In the real experiment](http://cms.web.cern.ch/news/about-higgs-boson), a number of events

[image]

with two photons, for example, have been accumulated so that the claim of seeing a Higgs like particle  has been established statistically.

[image]

A lot of work remains to make sure that the bump seen has really the decay branching ratios and spin and statistics expected from the SM before the discovery of the Higgs boson is established unequivocally. Then we could state with some certainty that the Standard Model which depends on the existence of a *Higgs field* is validated.

So it should be clear that each individual event is not like a spider that can be dissected. It is an instant of the materialization of the fields and the experiment has to accumulate enough events to statistically establish an observation that validates a hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks for your words here. This gives me some needed perspective, and yes I am certainly not well versed in elementary particle physics, only a computer scientist pursuing some comprehension here. I also somewhat understand the sheer volume of readings needed to confirm the existence of a Higgs. Still I am a bit confused, is it not true the Higgs field is not just some uniform x,y,z grid of the whole universe, but with well defined base-charge holding curvature giving mass in a discreet way? I wish my vocabulary and concepts in this area were greater.

Comment: @GaretClaborn: It's not that much--- the Higgs is a relativistically invariant superconductor filling space (this is not a simplification nor is it much of an analogy, it's a direct 1-1 correspondence of the physical ideas), a superconductor is a charged superfluid. The issue is that if you don't know quantum mechanics, everything is mysterious. I would suggest reading a book on quantum mechanics, the standard ones, plus Dirac's "The Principles of Quantum Mechanics". Then learn path-integration, then the rest of standard particle physics is straightforward.

Comment: A field is not a grid, it is continuous, and manifests wherever there is enough energy for matter to appear. Since you have a science background you might be able to explore the teaching resources of CERN http://education.web.cern.ch/education/Chapter2/Intro.html  on the left are links to a lot of simple lectures.

Comment: @annav Right right, I was being oversimplistic, really I think more along the lines of manifolds, somewhat understand the difference in fields. Thanks very much, will be looking into this.